# android service shared preferences

Tags: android, android-service, sharedpreferences, android-lifecycle

I'm building an app with a service that stores objects in a database. Its keeps a list of the objects in memory until there is a certain number and the saves them to the database. This means that when the service is stopped, the objects that are in memory are lost.

To solve this, I'm trying to save the list of objects in the app's shared preferences whenever the service's `onDestroy()` method is called and restore them when it is restarted in `onCreate()`. I've managed to be able to restore the list from shared preferences, the problem I'm having is storing it.

Namely, when the app is re-run, `onCreate()` is called around half a second before `onDestory()`. This means that the service tries to retrieve the list before it is stored.

Am I going about this the right way? Or is there an alternative to keeping data between when a service is stopped and when it is restarted?

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply commit the data to the db in the onDestroy method?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html):
"Most Android apps need to save data, even if only to save information about the app state during *onPause()* so the user's progress is not lost."

Move your storing logic to *onPause()* method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the storing logic needs to go in the service, as it will be able to run long after the activity connected to it is paused. And as far as I know, a service doesn't have an `onPause()` method

Comment: Don't you want to store the sensitive data when it is appearing/changing?

Comment: One object can affect the objects that are immediately before or after it, so I keep a list of them as they come in. These get stored when they can no longer affect other objects. The problem is I can lose object that might hold a lot of useful information if the service is destroyed before it can be saved to the database

Comment: As you cannot relay on *onDestroy()* callback you may want to save a "snapshot" of the sensitive data periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I think I'll go with that instead